# offset error after the 2nd texture access

Tags: opengl-es

I want my fragment shader to travers a serialized quad tree.
When a inner node is found the rg vales are interpreded as an index into the same texture.
A blue value of 0 marks an inner node.

In a first step a pointer is read from a 2x2 subimage at position 0x0 using the provided uv coords.
Then that pointer is used to access another 2x2 portion of the same texture.
However for each child of the root node there is an increasing offset error that results in the wrong color.

Here is my shader (for debug porpusses the loop is fixed at one iteration, so only 2 levels of the quad tree get accessed).

Also for debugging I did put a red 2x2 image at the location of the top left child a green image for the top right, blue for the bottom left and yellow for the bottom right child.

The resulting image is this:
[image]

I am completly clueless. Can one of you think of a reason why this is happening?
I checkt all the coordinate conversion and calculations 3 times they are all correct.

Here is the shader:

```
// virtual_image.fs
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D t_atlas;
uniform sampler2D t_tree;

uniform vec2 gridpoolSize;
uniform vec2 atlasTileSize;
uniform vec2 atlasSize;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

const float LEAF_MARKER = 1.0;
const float NODE_MARKER = 0.0;

const float CHANNEL_PERECISION = 255.0;

vec2 decode(const vec2 vec){
    return vec * CHANNEL_PERECISION;
}

void main ()
{
    vec4 oc = vec4(1); // output color
    vec4 tColor = texture2D(t_tree, v_texcoord); // only for debuging
    vec4 aColor = texture2D(t_atlas, v_texcoord); // only for debuging
    // oc = mix(tColor, aColor, 0.5);

    highp vec2 localCoord = v_texcoord;

    // by convention the root node starts at [0,0]
    // so we read the first pointer relative to that point
    // we use the  invertedGridpoolSize to convert the local coords in local coords of the first grid at [0,0]
    highp vec3 pointer = texture2D(t_tree, localCoord / gridpoolSize).rgb;// pointer is correct at this point!

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 1; i++) {

        // divides the local coords into 4 quadrants
        localCoord = fract(localCoord * 2.0); // localCoord is correct!


        // branch
        if(pointer.b <= NODE_MARKER + 0.1){
            highp vec2 index = decode(pointer.rg);// index is correct!
            highp vec2 absoluteCoord = (localCoord + index) / gridpoolSize;// absoluteCoord is correct!
            // we have a inner node get next pointer and continue
            pointer = texture2D(t_tree, absoluteCoord).rgb;
            oc.rgb = pointer.rgb; // this point in the code introduces a growing offset, I don't know where this comes from. BUG LOCATION
            //gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);
        } else {
            if(pointer.b >= LEAF_MARKER - 0.1){
                // we have a leaf
                vec2 atlasCoord = ((decode(pointer.rg)  * atlasTileSize) / atlasSize) + (localCoord * (atlasTileSize / atlasSize));
                vec4 atlasColor = texture2D(t_atlas, atlasCoord);
                //vec4 atlasCoordColor = vec4(atlasCoord,0,1);
                //gl_FragColor = mix(atlasColor, vec4(localCoord, 0, 1), 1.0);
                //gl_FragColor = vec4(localCoord, 0, 1);
                oc = vec4(1,0,1,1);
            } else {
                // we have an empty cell
                oc = vec4(1,0,1,1);
            }
        }
    }
    //oc.rgb = pointer;
    //oc.rgb = oc.rgb * (255.0 / 20.0 );
    gl_FragColor = oc;
}
```

For details on how to serialize a quad tree as a texture take a look at this paper: [Octree Textures on the GPU](http://www.aracknea-core.com/sylefeb/octreetex/octree_textures_on_the_gpu.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that its a rounding problem.

The code in the decode function hast to be changed to:

```
vec2 decode(const vec2 vec){
    return floor(0.5 + (vec * CHANNEL_PERECISION))
}
```

The values returns should have been indexes of int but where slightly to small like 5.99 instead of 6.